# Sustained Troll attack

Tags: discussion, off-topic

One particularly troublesome person has been trolling this site.
Happily the moderators have contained the problem and I want to express my appreciation for their good work.

Answer (score 13):

I agree, the moderators have thus far done a great job!

I would like to bring up what discussed in the chat in regards to this:

- Don't poke the troll.  As much fun as it sounds like, anything you do to him, comments and the like, feed his need for the next attack.  Just report the answer/question or vote to close if you can.
- Be sure its him (or any other troll) before action is taken.  We still need to maintain a friendly attitude to other new people.
- Don't edit any of the obvious stupid questions into good questions, it still feeds him.  If you like the concept of the question, wait for his to close, and open up a real, proper question of your own.
- They're rolling everything of his under [one account](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4595/handy-andy), so we should see everything go there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, those are good points.

Comment: Thanks @rfusca for listing out the plan of action. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: I noticed a picture that I've seen floating around on Usenet where someone enjoys extolling the virtues of point-and-shoot cameras over DSRLs, provoking long flamewars. I guess it was inevitable that this person or someone inspired by him or her would show up here.

Comment: Well, we're just not going to engage in a flame war (hopefully).  We (the community) have the power and this is a time we just need to use it appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Think of it as a good opportunity to work for the Deputy badge. :)

In seriousness, it probably helpful to keep a watch on this page: https://photo.stackexchange.com/review
(See the little explanation box on the right of the page.)

Comment: That is a useful page.